# Basic: error in swift code but cannot find out why

Tags: ios, swift, runtime-error

hi i am very new to swift coding language and i am learning a tutorial now. 
i am running a tip calculator course from udemy.

as far as i can see i have the same code the teacher is using but this course is from ios 8 early 9 times i do not know if the swift or xcode language changed over time .

this is my code.

```html
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtmaelcost: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtTip: UITextField!
    
        @IBOutlet weak var lblTipcalculated: UILabel!
    
    var mealCost = ""
    var tipPercentage = ""
    var awnser : Float = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func btnCalculate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    calculateTip()
    
    }
    
    @IBAction func btnClear(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
  
    func calculateTip() -> Bool {
        tipPercentage = txtTip.text!
        mealCost = txtmaelcost.text!
        
        let fMealCost = (mealCost as NSString).floatValue
        let fTipprecentage = (tipPercentage as NSString).floatValue
        
        awnser = fMealCost * (fTipprecentage * 0.01)
        
        lblTipcalculated.text = "(awnser)"
    return true
    }

}
```

now my error is in the middle   calculateTip()
it says (Result of call calculateTip() is unused )

i bet this is a easy fix for some of you, but i am unable to figuring out why this is going wrong.

if anyone needs any additional information please ask me.

Comment: remove return type from `calculateTip` function because there is no need of it as how you are using this!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the function `calculateTip` is defined to return a boolean value, which it does, but in the *call* to the function, you never use the value. You just call the function without assigning the result to a variable or otherwise using it.

Perhaps you would like to remove the `-> Bool` in your function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Its not an error, It is a warning.

It means that you have called the method `calculateTip()` which return Bool value. But you have not used this result anywhere.

To suppress this warning just to this:

```
print(calculateTip())
```

Now you are printing the output of the method, means the output is used now!

Answer (score 0):

It's a warning. What the compiler try to explain It's that your function returns a boolean value but You are not using it on your code.

If you want to solve the warning (not an error) you do something like that...

```
if calculateTip()
{
    // Do something here
}
else
{
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to silence this warning, put `@discardableResult` in function declaration:

```
@discardableResult fund calculateTip() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Another way:

```
_ = calculateTip()
```

But I think its better to use first option. Will keep your code clean.